# Display dialog when GPS is offline

Tags: android

Is the following dialog a native feature? If so, how can I use it?

[image: Activate GPS dialog]

Comment: Just `customized Dialog` Nothing else....Search on `Google`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out for AlertDialog info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

You can easily have the dialog take the user to the location services, where they can enable GPS. Just have one of your buttons  onclick listeners (like the Settings button) cause an intent like this

```
Intent toGPSEnable = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
StartActivity(toGPSEnable)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not system dialog. If you want such in your own app you need to make it yourself.